# How to include required OpenGL libraries?

Tags: opengl

I could only find gl/gl.h and gl/glu.h in my VC++. How to get GLFW and GLEW and GLUT?

And why do we include GLEW, GLFW and GLUT? Which library is must and why?

Comment: Pick a book or tutorial on OpenGL, instead of going by yourself. There's a lot of pitfalls that can happen due to stale data on the internet.

Comment: can you suggest a book or tutorial??? I have tried searching for it but none could actually make me comfortable.

Comment: _OpenGL 4.0 Shading Language Cookbook_, _OpenGL Superbible 6th edition_, _OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide_ are good from what I've seen. As for the tutorials, [try this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/32876/14025) for a comprehensive list.

Comment: neither of GLEW, GLFW or GLUT is necdessary for Opengl programming; we use them just because they provide somewhat standard and portable solutions for things that are not directly linked to graphics programming, but that has to be dealt with anyways. For example, GLUT and GLFW(pick one of them) both provide window and opengl context to render to, as well as simplify user input/event processing. There are other alternatives, including Qt. GLEW initializes pointers to OpenGL extension functions, but is not the only way to get them(after all you can use wglGetProcAddress on Windows for example).

Answer (score 1):

The difference between them is here:

[Post in StackOverflow about the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719329/772739)

And you have to download and install them as they tell in their official website and documentation. But first differenciate between them and choose the one that helps you out.